# Starting a service from tomcat in Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, service

I am making a GUI in Java, which starts and stops services.
I am using the following code to start the service:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process exec = runtime.exec(serviceExecutablePath);
```

where `serviceExecutablePath` is

```
nohup /usr/local/Services/Deployable/AccountNameCleanServiceJar/AccountNameCleanService.sh >/dev/null
```

I am using Tomcat as my server. Every time I start a service it gets started but after some time stops by itself.

However on running the same command from Unix console its running fine.
I am stuck why this is happening, can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at Apache's [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)?

Comment: thanks for the reply ,i had a doubt if its like that , then it should not have allowed me to start the service even,but service is getting started and gets stop in a while.